# VS Code not showing top menu bar Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10, visual-studio-code

[image: top bar is not showing see closely]

I just install VS Code to my Ubuntu 18.10 distro but after installation top menu bar isn't visible on VS Code. What can i do??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the menu bar click on

> File > Settings

Type:

> window.titleBarStyle

and change it to:

> custom

Comment: Sorry, in this case we can change design of menu bar, but question was about "...not showing top menu...". In case your answer we use **File** option as part of invisible menu. Sounds like a logical loop.

Comment: Please follow the steps and tell me what happen. I had the same issue with vscode on my ubundu 18.10... solve it doing exactly what i mentioned on the answer.

Answer (score 4):

1. on the left bottom you will a setting icon,click on the setting icon.
2. in the search box type : `window.titleBarStyle`
3. change the Window: Title Bar Style to `custom`
4. restart the VS editor.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Changing the GTK theme solved the problem. Just install gnome-tweak-tool, go to Appearance and change the Applications theme from *Yaru* to something else (like *Adwaita*).

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been fixed in release 1.31.0 (January 2019 (I know it's weird as we are a week in February already...)), I have reset my theme to Yaru and the `"window.titleBarStyle"` to `"native"` and it works perfectly.

#### Update

In update 1.32, the `"window.titleBarStyle": "native"` has been set back to default in Linux as well. (It was set to default to `"custom"` I believe due to the issue mentioned in this question, and now it's back to `"native"`.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to make menu visible and then in View menu choose Toggle Menu Bar.

Or to restore the menu bar is to trigger the `View: Toggle Menu Bar` command in the command palette (<kbd>F1</kbd>).

[image: VS Code]